# Botón para exportar toda una tablaBD a Excel

Tags: php, mysql, html5, ajax

Tengo una duda, hay alguna forma  de exportar todo el contenido de una **tabla BD** a  **Excel** sin mostrar esa tabla en la pagina web.

En el momento lo que utilizo es una pagina de reportes.php  esta pagina tiene un código  **boostrap** para mostrar una tabla **html** *'table_wrapper'* como id.

```
 <!-- TABLE-->
          <div style='overflow:auto' id='table_wrapper'>
            <table class="table table-hover" id="TableId">
              <thead>
                <tr>
                  <th>Canal</th>
                  <th>Razon_Social</th>
                  <th>Sucursal</th>
                  <th>Producto</th>
                  <th>Codigo Producto</th>
                  <th>Estado</th>
                  <th>Historico</th>
                  <th>Fecha_Mod.</th>
                </tr>
              </thead>
              <tbody>
                 <?php

                       $pdo = Database::connect();
                       $sql = "SELECT ubicacion.nom_canal, ubicacion.nom_rz, ubicacion.ide_sucursal, productos.nom_producto, productos.cod_producto, inventario.estado_producto, inventario.historico, inventario.fecha_mod 
                          FROM inventario INNER JOIN ubicacion 
                          ON  (ubicacion.ide_canal = inventario.ide_ubicacion ) 
                          INNER JOIN productos 
                          ON (productos.ide_producto = inventario.ide_producto) ";

                       foreach ($pdo->query($sql) as $row) {
                                echo '<tr>';
                                echo '<td>'. $row['nom_canal'] . '</td>';
                                echo '<td>'. $row['nom_rz'] . '</td>';
                                echo '<td>'. $row['ide_sucursal'] . '</td>';
                                echo '<td>'. $row['nom_producto'] . '</td>';
                                echo '<td>'. $row['cod_producto'] . '</td>';
                                echo '<td>'. $row['estado_producto'] . '</td>';
                                echo '<td>'. $row['historico'] . '</td>';
                                echo '<td>'. $row['fecha_mod'] . '</td>';
                                echo '</tr>';
                       }
                       Database::disconnect();
                 ?>
              </tbody>
            </table>
          </div>
            <!-- PAGINACION TABLA -->
```

[codigo boostrap]

Despues utilizo una funcion js:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
     $("#btnExport").click(function(e) {
        var es_firefox = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf('firefox') > -1;

        if (es_firefox ) {
          window.open('data:application/vnd.ms-excel,' + encodeURIComponent($('#table_wrapper').html()));
          e.preventDefault();
        }else{
         var a = document.createElement('a');  

         // calculamos la fecha actual 
          var hoy = new Date();
          dia = hoy.getDate(); 
          mes = hoy.getMonth() + 1 ;
          anio= hoy.getFullYear();
          fecha_actual = String(dia + "_" + mes + "_" + anio);

        // Pagina que hizo el llamado 
        //var pagina = document.getElementById('pagina').value;
        var pagina = 'ReportePernod';


         //Obtenemos los valores de la tabla 
         var data_type = 'data:application/vnd.ms-excel';
         var table_div = document.getElementById('table_wrapper');
         var table_html = table_div.outerHTML.replace(/ /g, '%20');


         a.href = data_type + ', ' + table_html;
         a.download = pagina + ' '+ fecha_actual + '.xls';
         a.click();

         e.preventDefault();  
        }

     });
});
```

Esta función me permite descargar lo que se muestre en la tabla *wrapper*, sin embargo requiero bajar todo un histórico, que no necesariamente  debe mostrar la información en la pagina, y no utilizar recursos innecesarios.

¿Sabrían otra forma de descargar toda la información?

Comment: Con php puro puedes exportar en CSV sin mostrarle al usuario la data, ahora bien como mencionaste excel no se si te interesa este formato, solo debes agregar estas lineas al inicio de tu archivo php `$nombrearchivo = "Reporte-" . date( 'd-m-y' ) . ".xls"; 
header("Content-type: application/vnd.ms-excel");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$nombrearchivo");`

Comment: Hola @YoAlbert, con este codigo bajaria toda la info de la pagina donde agrege  el codigo.

En otras palabras debo crear otro archivo .php con solo la consulta, o debo crear una tabla   y esa tabla es la que me descarga la info.??

Gracias por tu ayuda.

Comment: Así es, crear un nuevo archivo php, créalo y asegúrate que la información se despliega, cuando ya estés seguro de que todo funciona bien, agregas las lineas que te pase.